# S3 Get Object API returning status 204 (libcloud)

Tags: python, amazon-s3, libcloud

So, I'm using libcloud on python to access an S3 bucket and download CSV files to process them.

It all works fine, but today I got this error:

```py
[...]
return self.driver.download_object_as_stream(obj=self, chunk_size=chunk_size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libcloud/storage/drivers/s3.py", line 537, in download_object_as_stream
    return self._get_object(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages/libcloud/storage/base.py", line 753, in _get_object
    raise LibcloudError(
libcloud.common.types.LibcloudError: <LibcloudError in <libcloud.storage.drivers.s3.S3StorageDriver object at 0x7f59f6ec5670> 'Unexpected status code: 204'>
```

I saw that the library uses [Amazon S3's Get Object API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/API_GetObject.html), but I can't understand why or how it could return this status code. Has anyone seen this? I'm not even sure how to handle it or what does it mean...